# UK Application Deception

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, deception

A friend applied for a UK visitor visa. In this visa application, he mentioned that he went to Chine and Singapore for a holiday. His passport does not have any visa or stamp from these countries. Will they refuse his application for deception? Can the UK find out he didn’t visit those countries?

Comment: Did he actually visit China (or Chile?) and Singapore or not? Lack of passport stamps alone does not prove deception, but could invite further scrutiny if the country is known (in case of China) for systematically stamping foreign passports (although there are other explanations); the ECO is authorized to request further information.

Comment: Is that a new passport? If that's the case, that will not raise as many eyebrows as if it were a passport valid during the person's holiday. If they aren't visa-exempt for those countries, are they eligible for an e-visa for the mentioned countries? Missing visas can give all that the ECO needs to refuse for deception

Comment: Well, it is a new passport with no visa from any country.

Comment: You really need to clarify this question. There is a difference between "did not visit", "visited but didn't get a stamp" and "visited with the old passport, so of course the new passport doesn't have a stamp". Which of those three cases applies here?

Comment: Is Chine meant to be China or Chile? And did you actually visit these places or not?

Comment: @AlexQute, why did you roll back the edit? It is normal here for others to improve the question and yours can do with editing. Please do answer the questions asked in the comments (you can edit those in,) but please do not roll back edits without mentioning what is wrong in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he did not visit those countries and it comes out he will likely get a ban, but if he went and 'just' does not have the stamps, but can prove it in an other way it will be fine.

I do not think the UK visa officials will be able to check with China and Singapore directly but those wanting a visa can be interviewed and in the case of missing stamps it is guarantied that the officer will ask about those visits (and likely will know a lot more about the countries and what you experience there than someone who has never been can come up with.)
And when showing up at the border (or airport) with a visa you can get interviewed again, with the same risk of being found out on a lie, and a ban for deception as result.

If it comes out he lied in the application a ban for deception is very likely and that will make traveling abroad in the future very hard.

As mentioned in the comments, the interviews for visa are not as common as I thought, but interviews on entry are still quite common.

Comment: AFAIK the UK does not routinely interview applicants for a visitor visa as part of the application process itself. Inventing a travel history probably wouldn’t do much to improve the chances of success if the rest of the application was weak eg ties to home country probably carry much more weight.

Comment: Interviews for UK visitor visas are unheard of. Only a small minority of long term visa applicants are interviewed. 'Missing stamps' are unlikely to cause any particular issue since there are many reasons for a visit not having a corresponding stamp (new passports, or the country in question not issuing a stamp either systematically or by accident).

Comment: Updated the answer based on the comments.

Answer (score 5):

Singapore stopped stamping passports a long time back. So, you can just declare that. I have done that and no other questions was asked. Regarding china, I understand that the passport will be stamped. Was there any reason why it was not stamped?

In any case, answer truthfully and you won't be denied for deception. Include documents to provide that you entered singapore and china. For example, you will get an email just after entering Singapore, if you filled out the SG Arrival card. China may have something similar.

In any case, do not lie that you didn't enter. If they found out otherwise, they will ban you for deception.